# Android: when should application notify the server client disconnection

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I read the Last Safe Method to be called before killing the application in Android is OnPause.
Suppose I have client running on Android that is a part of location based Client/Server application. I have some design issues:

When I create the main activity I though it is logicall to start a service that connects to the server (running on my computer) and updating it in with the user location.
Now, when the application is active I want to present the user some information. Even if the user paused the activity I want the service keep running in the background and update the server. I also want the server to know when user disconnected.
Now because OnPause is the last safe method guaranteed to be called by the system, I don't know where it's best to **notify the server of user disconnection**.

Comment: Do you want to notify the user of failed server connection or the server of a problem?

Comment: I'll edit it to be clear

Comment: What do you mean by user disconnect?